# How to include annual data in a monthly dataset

Tags: r, database, time-series, na, zoo

I am trying to add annual company data to monthly ones. Since the annual data is reported at specific months and not always updated every 12 months, I need the annual values to match the month in the monthly dataset and then carry them over until the next available datapoint for that specific company, if there is one.

The dataset consists of thousands of companies with unique IDs, which generally do not report in the same annual patterns. Two subsequent ReportMonths do not have to be in the same month. Also, there can be years where I do not have a ReportMonth and therefore no annual data for that year.

I made sure that in every month where I have some annual data, the whole row of annual variables is never NA. Below is an example of the structure and where I am stuck right now.

```
        id     Date  MonVariable  ReportMonth  AnnVariable
1  ABCDEFG  1999-02            1         <NA>         <NA>
2  ABCDEFG  1999-01            2         <NA>         <NA>
3  ABCDEFG  1998-12            3         <NA>         <NA>
4  HIJKLMN  2019-08            4         <NA>         <NA>
5  HIJKLMN  2019-07            5         <NA>         <NA>
6  HIJKLMN  2019-06            6         <NA>         <NA>
7  HIJKLMN  2019-05            7      2019-05          101
8  HIJKLMN  2019-04            8      2018-06          113
```

I tried using `dplyr:group_by(id)` and then `zoo:na.locf(x, na.rm = F, fromLast = T, maxgap = 12)` for every annual variable.

I could carry them over for a maximum of 12 months, which can be seen in row 8 where the annual variable is from the reporting date from around one year ago.

But there are two issues. The first is that around the break from one company to the next, the latest values of the company below are still missing (rows 4-6). However, I would like to have the last available value for them as well, just as below.

```
        id     Date  MonVariable  ReportMonth  AnnVariable
1  ABCDEFG  1999-02            1         <NA>         <NA>
2  ABCDEFG  1999-01            2         <NA>         <NA>
3  ABCDEFG  1998-12            3         <NA>         <NA>
4  HIJKLMN  2019-08            4      2019-05          101
5  HIJKLMN  2019-07            5      2019-05          101
6  HIJKLMN  2019-06            6      2019-05          101
7  HIJKLMN  2019-05            7      2019-05          101
8  HIJKLMN  2019-04            8      2018-06          113
```

I think `na.locf` does not fill them until the break, because the last annual variables of the companies are often also missing, so the "gap" between the rows of the closest 2 values is bigger than 12 (I guess the `dplyr` grouping does not work the way I understand it so far).

The second issue is when for one specific company there is a larger gap than 12 months between the reported annual values. `na.locf` also does not fill anything, again because the gap is bigger than `maxgap`. In that case, I would like to carry over the last available value to the following 12 months, just as below.

```
         id     Date  MonVariable  ReportMonth  AnnVariable
 1  HIJKLMN  2019-08            1      2019-08          149
 2  HIJKLMN  2019-07            2         <NA>         <NA>
 3  HIJKLMN  2019-06            3         <NA>         <NA>
 4  HIJKLMN  2019-05            4      2018-05          101
 5  HIJKLMN  2019-04            5      2018-05          101
 6  HIJKLMN  2019-03            6      2018-05          101
 7  HIJKLMN  2019-02            7      2018-05          101
 8  HIJKLMN  2019-01            8      2018-05          101
 9  HIJKLMN  2018-12            9      2018-05          101
10  HIJKLMN  2018-11            1      2018-05          101
11  HIJKLMN  2018-10            2      2018-05          101
12  HIJKLMN  2018-09            3      2018-05          101
13  HIJKLMN  2018-08            4      2018-05          101
14  HIJKLMN  2018-07            5      2018-05          101
15  HIJKLMN  2018-06            6      2018-05          101
16  HIJKLMN  2018-05            7      2018-05          101
17  HIJKLMN  2018-04            8      2017-06          113
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the data into ids using `by`, then make a `substring` out of year and `"05"` month. Check with `ifelse` if it's available and assign `NA` if not. For the `"AnnVariable"` we could make a factor out of `"ReportMonth"` using sorted `"AnnVariable"` as labels (should scale up to your data, but check this carefully e.g. if `"AnnVariable"` is sorted as shown in your example).

```
df1 <- within(df1, {
  ReportMonth <- do.call(c, by(df1, df1$id, function(s) {
    r <- ifelse(as.numeric(substring(s$Date, 6)) >= 5, 
                paste0(substr(s$Date, 1, 4), "-05"),
                paste0(as.numeric(substr(s$Date, 1, 4)) - 1, "-05"))
    return(ifelse(r %in% s$ReportMonth, r, NA))
  }))
  AnnVariable <- factor(ReportMonth, labels=sort(as.numeric(na.omit(AnnVariable))))
})
df1
#        id    Date MonVariable ReportMonth AnnVariable
# 1 ABCDEFG 1999-02           1        <NA>        <NA>
# 2 ABCDEFG 1999-01           2        <NA>        <NA>
# 3 ABCDEFG 1998-12           3        <NA>        <NA>
# 4 HIJKLMN 2019-08           4     2019-05         100
# 5 HIJKLMN 2019-07           5     2019-05         100
# 6 HIJKLMN 2019-06           6     2019-05         100
# 7 HIJKLMN 2019-05           7     2019-05         100
# 8 HIJKLMN 2019-04           8     2018-05          90
```

#### Edit

If the time variations are more complicated you could look into `cut` converting the dates into `numeric`s.

```
df1[8, 4] <- "2018-06"

# helping variables
df1$Date.num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df1$Date))
df1$ReportMonth.num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df1$ReportMonth))

df1 <- within(df1, {
  ReportMonth <- do.call(c, by(df1, df1$id, function(s) {
    n <- rev(na.omit(s$ReportMonth))
    res <- cut(s$Date.num, c(gsub("\\D", "", n), range(s$Date.num)), labels=c(n, n[2]))
    return(as.character(res))
  }))
  AnnVariable <- factor(ReportMonth, labels=sort(as.numeric(na.omit(AnnVariable))))
})[1:5]
#        id    Date MonVariable ReportMonth AnnVariable
# 1 ABCDEFG 1999-02           1        <NA>        <NA>
# 2 ABCDEFG 1999-01           2        <NA>        <NA>
# 3 ABCDEFG 1998-12           3        <NA>        <NA>
# 4 HIJKLMN 2019-08           4     2019-05         100
# 5 HIJKLMN 2019-07           5     2019-05         100
# 6 HIJKLMN 2019-06           6     2019-05         100
# 7 HIJKLMN 2019-05           7     2019-05         100
# 8 HIJKLMN 2019-04           8     2018-06          90
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", "HIJKLMN", 
"HIJKLMN", "HIJKLMN", "HIJKLMN", "HIJKLMN"), Date = c("1999-02", 
"1999-01", "1998-12", "2019-08", "2019-07", "2019-06", "2019-05", 
"2019-04"), MonVariable = 1:8, ReportMonth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "2019-05", "2018-05"), AnnVariable = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "100", "90")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A problem here is that the ReportMonth is not always the same (I edited my example in the question to reflect this). Is there a way to modify your approach to make it more general? Also, to use your factor-method, is it possible to create the ReportMonth factor inside the "by" because the ReportMonth is not unique across the whole dataset.